# Java RegularExpression

Tags: java, regex

Please help me to show the the correct output for this. how can i get this true i always get false in my output.

```
    System.out.print("Enter Time: ");
    str = scanner.nextLine();

    String regextime = "((([0-1]?[0-2])|(0?[0-9])):[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9][ ]?[AaPp][Mm]) | ((([2]?[0-4])|([0-1]?[0-9])):[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9])";
    //12 hr
    //(([0-1]?[0-2])|(0?[0-9])):[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9][ ]?[AaPp][Mm]
    //24hr
    //(([2]?[0-4])|([0-1]?[0-9])):[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]
    System.out.println(str.matches(regextime));
```

Comment: What is the expected input and output? If your input doesn't match the regex, you are bound to get false in your output.

Comment: it would print the statement true? uhm i need to base it from the given statement. thanks sir!

Comment: @ashutosh is my statement correct? my example input is 1:25:25 am it should print true or 23:23:59 is shoudl also print true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex patterns do not allow random whitespace. You have two large regex patterns separated by a `|` in the middle. The `|` has a space on each side. The regex matcher assumes that those spaces are intended to be part of the pattern so for a time with `am` or `pm` it expects a trailing space, and for a 24 hour time it expects a leading space.

Change your pattern to:

```
String regextime = "((([0-1]?[0-2])|(0?[0-9])):[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9][ ]?[AaPp][Mm])|((([2]?[0-4])|([0-1]?[0-9])):[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9])";
```

Or if you wish to keep the whitespace for clarity, you can add a flag to your pattern `(?x)` to tell it to ignore whitespace. You must then escape all whitespace you wish to keep so you must add `\\` in front of the space in the character class preceding `AM/PM`.

```
String regextime = "(?x)((([0-1]?[0-2])|(0?[0-9])):[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9][\\ ]?[AaPp][Mm]) | ((([2]?[0-4])|([0-1]?[0-9])):[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9])";
```